# Assign a Perl Array to Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, perl

I was attempting to integrate Perl code with JavaScript and came across an issue where I simply wanted to see the output of an Array I have stored within Perl. The following code gives me the proper elements within the array I have stored but I'm not able to see the elements within JavaScript.

```
my @list_of_vendors;
while(!$resultSet->EOF) {
push @list_of_vendors, $resultSet->Fields("vendor")->Value;
    $resultSet->MoveNext;
}

print "The First Vendor is: " . $list_of_vendors[0]. "\n";
```

This Prints out `The First vendor is: 3D Systems` The following code doesn't seem to give me the results I want...

```
print <<ONE;
<html>
<body>
<h4> Test Vendor Array Javascript </h4>

<p id="demo"</p>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
var myVendorArray = @list_of_vendors;
document.write('<p> $list_of_vendors[0] is the same as myVendorArray[0] </p>');

</script>
</body>
</html>
ONE
```

I thought this would give me `3D Systems is the same as 3D Systems` but it gives a blank for the html screen.

Can anyone point out to me what I might be doing wrong? Or point me in the right direction to debug this using notepad++ or some other useful IDE for this. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Sorry not necessarily doesn't work but not giving me the results I think it is supposed to give...I want to see `3D Systems is the same as `3D Systems` on the html page... but for some reason this is not showing...

Comment: Have you tried doing a "View Source" to see the actually generated HTML? I think the problem will be pretty obvious . . .

Comment: @ruakh I tried that and noticed from here that I didn't get the results I wanted...The JavaScript picks up the variable but doesn't display it the way I want...It makes`@list_of_vendors` come back with a long string of vendors instead of being an array...Thanks for the suggestion #feelslikeanoob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in your code's heredoc is interpolated with Perl but interpreted by the client as JavaScript. So if you write

```
@list_of_vendors = ("Alice","Bob","Charlie");
...
print <<EOF;
...
<script>
var list_of_vendors = @list_of_vendors;
...
EOF
```

what the client will see is something like

```
var list_of_vendors = Alice Bob Charlie;
```

Perl has very good facilities for converting Perl data structures into the JSON notation, which is easily understood by JavaScript, so you should do something like:

```
use JSON;
$list_of_vendors_json = encode_json(\@list_of_vendors);
...
var list_of_vendors = $list_of_vendors_json;
...
```

in which case the browser would see something like:

```
var list_of_vendors = ["Alice","Bob","Charlie"];
```

and the rest of your code would work as intended.

Comment: Do I have to download JSON for this two work or is this a functionality within perl that can be made or is there some type of add-on for this?

Comment: Install `JSON` module with `cpan`.